# Calculating power for repeated measures in gpower

Tags: anova

I'm trying to calculate power for my repeated measures design in GPower.  I'm confident I have the right result for my design as a single measure ANOVA: 
2 factors, 3 levels each:

```
F tests - ANOVA: Fixed effects, special, main effects and interactions
Analysis:   A priori: Compute required sample size 
Input:  Effect size f   =   .4
α err prob  =   0.05
Power (1-β err prob)    =   .8
Numerator df    =   2
Number of groups    =   6
Output: Noncentrality parameter λ   =   10.240000
Critical F  =   3.155932
Denominator df  =   58
Total sample size   =   64
Actual power    =   0.803690
```

Then here's my set-up for repeated msrs:

```
F tests - ANOVA: Repeated measures, within-between interaction
Analysis:   A priori: Compute required sample size 
Input:  Effect size f   =   .4
α err prob  =   0.05
Power (1-β err prob)    =   .8
Number of groups    =   6
Repetitions =   4
Corr among rep measures =   0.5
Nonsphericity correction ε  =   1
Output: Noncentrality parameter λ   =   30.720000
Critical F  =   1.855810
Numerator df    =   15.000000
Denominator df  =   54.000000
Total sample size   =   24
Actual power    =   0.917180
```

Questions are: are my group numbers the same for repeated msrs as single measure?
 -are .5 correlation and 1 for nonsphericity correction standard?  And are these parameters derived from the design?

Thanks!